# How to re-enable admin bar with Buddypress active? (BP bar removed)

Tags: buddypress, admin-bar

How do I force WordPress/Buddypress to use the WordPress admin bar on the frontend?

I know that I can disable the BP bar with `define( 'BP_DISABLE_ADMIN_BAR', true );` in the config, but the admin bar does not show back up.

Comment: Jessica's function lead me to this... http://jeffersonsnewspaper.org/2012/tips-for-using-the-wordpress-admin-bar-with-buddypress/

Comment: What is the problem exactly? If that's an issue for the logged out users buddypress had released a patch to fix the problem. You can find the changes here: https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/6965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `wp-config.php`, put this:

`define( 'BP_USE_WP_ADMIN_BAR', true );`

Note you must put it in wp-config.php, I had it in functions.php first and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd re-enable it then use this to deactivate each one-by-one:
http://codex.buddypress.org/theme-development/modifying-the-buddypress-admin-bar/

Answer (score 0):

define( 'BP_DISABLE_ADMIN_BAR', false); or just delete that code might work, also check in your options on your dashboard in your profile Users->Your Profile