# Restore original WP admin bar after BuddyPress install

Tags: admin, buddypress, admin-bar

I want to re-enable the original WP admin bar after installing BuddyPress!

`define( 'BP_DISABLE_ADMIN_BAR', true );` completely disables the admin bar - don't want that.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/how-to-re-enable-admin-bar-with-buddypress-active-bp-bar-removed) tells us to check the [BuddyPress Codex page](http://codex.buddypress.org/theme-development/modifying-the-buddypress-admin-bar/), and I tried messing with those action hooks but didn't get any desired results.

What's missing? How do we get that admin bar back?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [buddypress 1.5](http://codex.buddypress.org/releases/version-1-5/#buddybaradmin-bar) you can use:

```
define( 'BP_USE_WP_ADMIN_BAR', true );
```

I use it in [bp-custom.php](http://codex.buddypress.org/extending-buddypress/bp-custom-php/) although it can go in *wp-config.php*

Comment: aaaaaargg. THANK YOU! Can't believe I missed that.